# Stop default safari search bar from re-appearing after anchor link is pressed

Tags: html, ios, mobile-safari

I have a one page website.

In small-screen format it is a long column which I am navigating with anchor links.

```
<a href="#destination>Go to destination</a>
```

-

```
<section id="destination">Link to here:</section>
```

Pretty basic.

In mobile Safari, as you scroll - the Address bar and the other interface stuff glides away to give you some more space. When you press the anchor link, it brings that section to the top of the window as intended... but also seems to reset the defaults of the Address bar and interface buttons below.

Is there a known way to stop this behavior?

Is it there so I can use the back button - or for good reason?

[image: mobile Safari interface when tucked away]

### VS

[image: after tapping anchor - the interface stuff reappears]

### EDIT

Since posting I have been fooling around with an offset.

```
  $(".global-menu a").on('click', function(event) {

    // instead, animate the scroll
    $('html,body').animate({
      // find how far it is from the top - then - don't go all that way
      // offset it a bit... 
      scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top - 10
    }, 0); // I don't want an animation... but this is working for reasons I don't understand.

    event.preventDefault();

  });
```

Comment: Interesting. It seems if you click a link and the hash value changes, the toolbar(s) appear. Would you be open to using JS to suppress this action?

Comment: RE: js - NO, I only use CSS3... hahaha  ---- just kidding. Yes Yes Yes. So, far I put in scroll offset - that for some reason suppresses it, but I'm looking for something more elegant and to the point. I'll add it above...

Comment: Apple has a viewport tag option or "minimal-ui" - that does the trick... but has major drawbacks ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle I threw together: http://fiddle.jshell.net/pLjtN/show/

And the JS:

```
$('.global-menu').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    var href = $(this).attr('href'),
        title = href.substring(1);

    // Prevent default behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    // Update location via history to mimic browser - We should probably check for history support
    history.replaceState({}, title, href);

    // Scroll to element
    $(href).get(0).scrollIntoView(true);
});
```

The `replaceState` is there to mimic browser function when clicking internal links - You can remove that if desired.

`scrollIntoView` is a native DOM method. I prefer it over setting a scrollTop since it avoids having to calculate the offset of the element. Also, I prefer it over jQuery animate (for performance reasons).

If you want to limit this to just iOS, you could wrap the entire event handler with a simple userAgent check like so:

```
if (/(iP(od|ad|hone))/g.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    ... code goes here ...
}
```

Here's the full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pLjtN/

Hope this helps! :)